# Could not handle else block inside while loop

Tags: ruby

I have a function that is suppose to force user to enter the values from `yes/no/y/n`. If user enter any other value then it should prompt the user for `INVALID ENTRY` message but it is not handling the `else` block as expected. Can someone let me know what's going wrong here?

```
def handleYesNo(value)
    begin
        val = ""

        while("#{value}" != "")
             if ("#{value.downcase}" == "yes" || "#{value.downcase}" == "y" || "#{value.downcase}" == "no" || "#{value.downcase}" == "n")
                    val = value
                    break
             else
                     puts "INVALID ENTRY"
             end
         end

         val

      rescue => e
           puts "Exception occurred - #{e}.".red
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that the user is never prompted to input a new `value`.  This means that if the `value` argument that's passed in is good, it will break, but will otherwise loop forever, since `value` will not be empty (the while loop condition) and it will never be reset to what you're looking for.  I'd reccomend something like this:

```
def handleYesNo(value)
  val = ""

  while("#{value}" != "")
    if ['yes', 'y', 'no', 'n'].include?(value.downcase)
      val = value
    else
      puts "INVALID ENTRY, Enter new value: "
      value = gets.chomp
    end
  end

  val
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you pass anything except yes/no/y/n to this method it will loop forever. It is because you have no `break` in the else block.

Maybe you want to prompt the user again? You could pass a boolean from the method to indicate if it was a success or not. And then you can take care of it is the calling code. Also the need for looping disappears in this scope.

**Sidenote**: you could rewrite the if criteria as:

```
['y','n','yes','no'].include? value.downcase
```

Answer (score 1):

```
answer = "" # the empty string

while answer != "yes" and answer != "y" and answer != "no" and answer != "n" do
  answer = gets.chomp
  if answer != "yes" and answer != "y" and answer != "no" and answer != "n" 
    puts "INVALID ENTRY"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of variety, here's another option. There's a gem called [interact](https://github.com/vito/interact) which does command-line prompting for you.

```
class MyCommandLine
  include Interactive

  def run
    ask "Is this cool?", choices: ["yes", "no"]
  end
end
```

Then when you run it as `MyCommandLine.new.run` it will prompt you, repeat questions as necessary, and automatically accept short answers (like "y" or "n") when they are sufficient to differentiate. There are even a few advanced features like rewind (when you enable this, a user hits the up arrow to revisit questions).